# Necesito crear una consulta para obtener el costo de un evento únicamente y agruparlo con su respectivo participante

Tags: sql-server, select, join, sql

necesito realizar una consulta que obtenga el nombre del participante, su departamento y la inversión total (cada participante se registra en un evento y cada evento tiene distintas sesiones en las cuáles el participante puede o no estar presente)

Por el momento tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT P.Nombre, P.Departamento, E.Costo AS Inversion FROM CDP_Eventos AS E 
INNER JOIN CDP_SesionEvento AS SE 
ON E.Id_Evento = SE.Id_Evento
INNER JOIN CDP_Asistencia AS A
ON A.Id_SesionEvento = SE.Id
INNER JOIN CDP_Participantes AS P 
ON A.Id_Participante = P.Id
GROUP BY P.Nombre, P.Departamento, E.Costo
```

Cualquier comentario será de gran ayuda ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Incluir definiciones de tablas y datos de prueba como imagen desalienta a los que quieran replicar tu problema, pues es mucho más dispendioso. Gracias por mostrar tus tablas, eso sí. Es muy importante para este tipo de preguntas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es una subconsulta de agregación:

```
SELECT  T.Nombre,
        SUM(T.Costo) AS 'Costo'
    FROM (SELECT    P.Nombre, P.Departamento, E.Costo AS Inversion 
            FROM CDP_Eventos AS E 
            INNER JOIN CDP_SesionEvento AS SE 
                ON E.Id_Evento = SE.Id_Evento
            INNER JOIN CDP_Asistencia AS A
                ON A.Id_SesionEvento = SE.Id
            INNER JOIN CDP_Participantes AS P 
                ON A.Id_Participante = P.Id
            GROUP BY P.Nombre, P.Departamento, E.Costo
    ) T
    GROUP BY T.Nombre
```

- La consulta original la tratas como subconsulta y la agrupas por `Nombre`
- y usar la función de agregación [`SUM()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para sumar el `Costo`por cada `Nombre`

Comment: Hola Patricio Moracho, muchas gracias por su comentario, lo que ocurre es lo siguiente: 

Al correr ese select, se obtiene la suma del costo pero de cada sesión de cada evento, por ejemplo 

Tengo el Evento A que tiene como costo 3000, este tiene 2 sesiones, Sesion 1 y Sesion 2, entonces, cuando realiza el select lo que hace es sumar el costo de Sesion 1 y Sesion 2, dando como resultado 6000 

En este caso, lo único que necesito es que tire 3000 como resultado

Comment: @BrayanMarín, entonces lo más sencillo es aplicar una agregación directamente a tu consulta. Verifica mi última edición.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente Query, agrupa tus registros por "nombre" del Participante y "descripción" del Evento, sumando su costo:

```
SELECT P.Nombre, E.Descripcion, SUM(E.Costo) AS Inversion 
FROM CDP_Eventos AS E 
INNER JOIN CDP_SesionEvento AS SE 
    ON E.Id_Evento = SE.Id_Evento
INNER JOIN CDP_Asistencia AS A
    ON A.Id_SesionEvento = SE.Id
INNER JOIN CDP_Participantes AS P 
    ON A.Id_Participante = P.Id
GROUP BY P.Nombre, E.Descripcion
```